# How to set up (create) sliced cylinder in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, geometry

How would you create a cylinder such as this?

http://www.eicac.co.uk/Images/SLICED-CYLINDER.png

I am guessing `gluCylinder` is not an option?

Comment: `gluCylinder()` would not be able to create that kind of cylinder. You'll have to generate vertices to describe the shape. Not difficult with some basic geometry. I think you should try to do this yourself, and let us know if you encounter difficulties. :)

Comment: I am pretty sure that is ***not*** a cylinder, the two ends are not perpendicular to the axis of revolution. You could produce this if you derived the plane equation for the top cylindrical section and used that to compute the heights for the vertices you will ultimately have to calculate yourself.

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Please upload your image here instead.

Answer (score 1):

*create it with one ribbon and two fans*

Lets assume that point `[0, 0, 0]` is at the center of the shape's base and Z-axis is up. Using constants from the Image.

## bottom cap

A simple disc.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN)
glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) // center
for angle from 0 to π (whatever step)
  double x = 0.5 * D * cos(angle);
  double y = 0.5 * D * sin(angle);
  glVertex3d(x, y, 0.0);
glEnd();
```

## side wall

We need to calculate the actual slope function.
It will be of the form `y = a * x + b` and have points `(0.0, H)` and `(0.5*D, H2)`.

Thus we have to solve for `a` and `b`. We have `b = H` and `a = (H2 - H) / 0.5 * D`

```
double a = (H2 - H) / 0.5 * D;
double b = H;

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)
for angle from 0 to π (whatever step)
  double x = 0.5 * D * cos(angle);
  double y = 0.5 * D * sin(angle);
  double height = a * x + b;
  glVertex3d(x, y, 0.0);
  glVertex3d(x, y, height);
glEnd();
```

## top cap

We combine the previous steps and seal the top.

```
double a = (H2 - H) / 0.5 * D;
double b = H;

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN)
glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, H) // center
for angle from 0 to π (whatever step)
  double x = 0.5 * D * cos(angle);
  double y = 0.5 * D * sin(angle);
  double height = a * x + b;
  glVertex3d(x, y, height);
glEnd();
```